# wampserver (PHP), where is the first time that the $_POST varibale is being set?

Tags: c#, php, wampserver

My  `$_POST` is empty (at the server) when I'm trying to post at other content type like `application/octet-stream`, or when i'm using WebClient method at my c# code (for sending a binary 8bit row data).
The server works fine for regular string and only for `ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Where can I check the variale `$_POST`? at the Request class?

Comment: PHP will only populate the post/request superglobals if you're sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. Any other data type is treated as plain binary and won't get parsed. If you ARE sending form data with an incorrect mime type, you can try extract POST data yourself from `php://input`. GET parameters come from the URL and are independent of the posted mime type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get raw POST data, use:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```